# Sending SMS from Website

Tags: sms, at-command

I want to know is it possible to send SMS text from my website to GSM modem in my local mechine using AT Command when my webserver and my computer basically two different mechines? I hope someone can give me some explaination of best practice to start sending SMS from a website, im new to this topic. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This answer is slightly off topic as you're asking specifically how to use your modem. But I've been looking into this recently and would suggest your best option is to go with one of the providers out there who help with this sort of thing (most are pay for services I'm afraid).

I'm using [Twilio](http://www.twilio.com) if that helps. They have a rich API and members of their team do answer questions on SO.

Comment: may i ask @Liath how you sending the AT Command from your website to your Modem? im still not clear on that.. Thanks

Comment: I'm not - Twilio have a .NET library (as well as many others), you call the method the text goes. It really is that simple!